# Override function in non derived c# class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, reference, overriding

I have the following class

```
public class classB : classA
```

which contains function `dostuff`

Now I have a class `SUPER`, which has an instance of B amongst its variables

```
classB SUPER_B;
```

and that has a 'redefinition' of 'dostuff' amongst its methods.
Basically, what I need is that when classB calls 'dostuff', it does not call its internal dostuff, but SUPER's dostuff implementation instead.

Substantially, I would need that, on SUPER's initialization, classB's 'dostuff' be replaced with SUPER's dostuff.

It'd sort of make sense if there was a way to retrieve B's 'dostuff''s reference, but I don't know how to achieve that.

I've looked into virtual and Func, but they seem to require that SUPER be a derivate of B

Comment: Please post the full code of the implementations of `dostuff` as defined on `classB` and `classA`, so we understand exactly what you are doing.

Comment: You've got some great suggestions here but that's as close as anyone can come without seeing some code or at least a statement of what your design motivation is.

Comment: Thanks all for the extraordinary support and suggestions. Posting code is troublesome since the class names I'm using are abstractions of multi page real classes. What I am eventually trying to achieve is what @dasblinkenlight suggested: "replacing a function with another function", through the settable delegate, I didn't know the methodology nor definition, so I was unable to search for that differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot force a method change upon a class from the outside. There are ways to achieve functionality like that when either (1) classB is designed in such a way as to support replacing its methods, e.g. though a settable delegate, or (2) if classB implements an interface, which you can implement, wrap classB inside it, and replace a method.

Example #1 - settable delegate:

```
class ClassB {
    public Action<int> dostuff {get;set;}
    public ClassB() {
        dostuff = myDoStuff;
    }
    void myDoStuff(int n) {
    }
}

class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var myB = new ClassB();
        myB.dostuff = myOverride;
    }
    void myOverride(int n) {
    }
}
```

Example #2 - interfaces.

```
interface IClassB {
    void dostuff(int n);
    void dosomething();
}
class ClassB : IClassB {
    void dostuff(int n) {
    }
    void dosomething() {
    }
}
class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var bb = new Override(new ClassB());
    }
    class Override : IClassB {
        private readonly IClassB inner;
        public Override(IClassB inner) {
            this.inner = inner;
        }
        void dostuff(int n) {
            // do not call inner.dostuff
        }
        void dosomething() {
            inner.dosomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to use decorator pattern: class `SUPER` has an instance of `classB` and uses it's methods. `SUPER` decorates all necessary methods of `classB`, and adds some new. For example:

```
public class SUPER {
  private classB SUPER_B = new classB();
  public void foo()  {
     SUPER_B.foo();
  }
  public void bar()  {
     SUPER_B.bar();
  }
  ...
  public void dostuff()
  {
       // don't call SUPER_B.bar(), but write your implementation
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case, why not just inherit classB?

Comment: @Dexter: OP says an instance of `classB` is a member of `SUPER`. I suppose that inheritance is not an option in his case. Otherwise, there is no question, since derived class can always overwrite non-sealed method.

Comment: @Dexter: cause you in this case enable access to ALL public/protected members of classB, which may be OP doesm't want. Cause this could be substantial change in your program architecture. Cause, may be, you can not as class is sealed....

Comment: This is actually one very good solution, too. Regarding prerequisites, a1ex07's intuitions are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that easily.

Instead you should design your `classB` for extensibility, such as add events to `classB` which you can handle in your `SUPER` class.